# Summing specific values in nested list Python

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
nested = [['a', 1], ['v', 2], ['a', 5], ['v', 3]]
```

I want to sum values in nested list for each letter value in list, so that output looks like this:

```
[['a', 6], ['v', 5]]
```

I have tried to play with for loops, but I couldnt find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a one liner for this using `reduce` and list comp, but I couldn't see it quickly.

```
nested = [['a', 1], ['v', 2], ['a', 5], ['v', 3]]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for i in nested:
    d[i[0]] += i[1]

retval = []    
for k, v in d.items():
    retval.append([k, v])

print(retval)  # [['a', 6], ['v', 5]]
```